# How to fix horizontal flickering lines on laptop screen?

Tags: display

Horizontal static flickering lines are all over my monitor. When connected to a external display the picture is displayed there. Once I updated the graphics driver the problem got solved but this time it failed. I have replaced the laptop screen and also the connector cable but the problem persists. Someone please help me.

[image: This is my laptop display]

Comment: Get your laptop serviced by a repair shop.

Comment: What do you mean by this time? Did you try to change the display refresh rate, something similiar occurd if i tried to increase the display refresh rate?